# How to determine if ESP32 MicroPython wifi access point is ready to show IP address?

Tags: wifi, esp32, micropython

I have an ESP32 microcontroller with MicroPython 1.19.1 that I'm setting up as a wifi access point. But, when I attempt to print the IP address with `print(f'{wlan.ifconfig()}')` it gets stuck in a reboot loop.

Here's the code in my boot.py:

```
from network import WLAN, AP_IF
from config import AP_NAME, AP_PASS

print('Starting in wifi access point mode...')
wlan = WLAN(AP_IF)
wlan.config(authmode=3, essid=AP_NAME, password=AP_PASS)
wlan.active(True)
while (wlan.active() == False):
    print('.')
print(f'SSID: {AP_NAME}')
print(f'Password: {AP_PASS}')
print(f'{wlan.ifconfig()}')
```

Commenting out the `print(f'{wlan.ifconfig()}')` fixes the reboot loop, as does inserting a delay just before the statement.

This leads me to believe the access point is not fully ready by the time I'm calling ifconfig(). But, I'm working under the assumption the `while (wlan.active() == False)` is supposed to take care of that. Though in the serial output, there's not a single dot printed to indicate it looped even once.

Serial output looks like this (after inserting a delay to mitigate the reboot loop):

```
Starting in wifi access point mode...
SSID: Lab
Password: ********
('192.168.4.1', '255.255.255.0', '192.168.4.1', '0.0.0.0')
```

If the while loop were actually waiting for the access point to come up, I would expect a few lines with dots between the 'Starting' message and the printing of SSID. So I'm thinking `wlan.active()` is just telling me what I set in the line above: `wlan.active(True)` and is not a true reflection of the access point's readiness.

I tried `help(wlan)` to see what methods might be available to determine the state of the access point. Some of the more promising ones and their results are shown below.

```
>>> wlan.active()
True
>>> wlan.isconnected()
False
>>> wlan.status()
>>>
```

I'm not surprised by `isconnected()` returning false since it's probably just for wifi station mode. I had high hopes for `status()`, but it only returns `None`

Every tutorial I've found so far uses the while loop to check `active()`, but obviously that's not working. Sticking a random delay in seems like a bad solution.

Is there a reliable way to ensure the access point is fully ready before asking for its IP address?